# git fetch/merge non-fast-forward changes?

Tags: git, merge, fetch

Guess I've a feature branch (so not `master`) which I changed (e.g. amend a commit, rebased or so) so it has non-fast-forward commits waiting for fetch/merge.

How can I do this?
When I git fetch, git tells me, that it needed to force the update. So the nff commits are locally now. And here I'm stuck.

I tried to `git rebase` or `git merge` but nothing does it like I want it to.

Finally I did it like

```
git merge origin/branchname
```

then I had a merge commit which logically does nothing.
And `git reset --hard` it back to the for last commit.

There must be a better way to do this... but how?

Comment: Forget about the git merge! When you do the "git reset --hard" in the branch of interesst, after the "git fetch", the nff commits are applied!

Answer (score 4):

If you have a merge `origin/branchname` which logically does nothing, that means the remote branch didn't have any commits of its own introducing new changes to your local branch:
The two branches are the same, even though your history has been rewritten.

So the simplest next step would be a `git push --force origin branchname` in order to replace the remote history of `branchname` by your local history.